# Can I keep a Watch app running in background?

Tags: location, watchkit, apple-watch, background-task, watchos

I know iOS allows background tasks to run and, for example, continue to receive location updates, but is it possible to do this in a watch app?
In Xcode 9.3, I have configured my app for  "background modes" and selected location, and that has created for the WatchKitExtension's an Info.plist, an entry for "Required background modes" of "App registers for location updates".

But my watch app still suspends when the screen turns off, and when it is in the dock.

The [App Programming Guide for watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html), however seems to exclude the possibility of running in the background to receive location updates as it only allows background processing for four classes of activity:

1. Background App Refresh Tasks. Use a WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask object to ...
2. Background Snapshot Refresh Tasks. Use a WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask object to update ...
3. Background Watch Connectivity Tasks. Use a WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask object to receive data sent by your iOS app ...
4. Background NSURLSession Tasks. ...

Other posts to SO indicate it's not possible, but proving a negative is difficult, so I'm asking again:

Am I "flogging a dead horse" by trying to keep the watch App operating in the background for receiving location updates, or is Xcode is making promises that WatchOS won't deliver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm delighted to be able to report that the horse I have been flogging for the past two weeks was not dead after all!

I have discovered an additional state in which my watch app will continue to run in the Background which does not require HKWorkoutSession.

These settings did the trick:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

and in watchKitExtension info.plist:

set UIBackgroundModes (Required background modes) to location (App registers for location updates)

And I repeat: I am NOT using healthKit

Now my app continues to run even when the screen is off and when the app is out of the Dock.

Comment: Wait a second: did you actually receive background information while the app is not on the foreground? I've been trying this, even using the `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` you mentioned, to no avail. As @Dávid Pásztor mentions below, even Apple says this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Yes, it continues to receive and process location updates when fully in the background, either out of the Dock or with the screen off. So much so, that I have had to add a user input to switch off the location updates to fully kill the app!
I'm still nervous that I have may have found a back door that Apple will slam when I go to publish. Give it a go yourself and

Comment: It works beautifully, even with `requestLocation()`! I schedule my application refresh so that i gets a single location, and it works beautifully! The reason why it didn't work before was because I forgot that location retrieving is asynchronous, and I was calling `setTaskCompleted()` before the location was ready.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

As the [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH21-SW10) clearly states, `WatchKit` apps cannot use background execution except for 3 use cases:

- Network operations using `URLSession`
- Playing audio using `WKAudioFilePlayer` or `WKAudioFileQueuePlayer`
- Run a workout using `HKWorkoutSession`

You cannot receive location updates in the background, according to the WatchKit Programming Guide, that should be done in the `iOS` app that is connected to your `watchOS` application.

Comment: Maybe I'm, asking the wrong question, but it's clearly possible.
There are apps that do continue to get location updates when the screen is off or when in the Dock. 
Both Strava and Nike+RunClub  record your track when the phone is left at home. I just installed them on my AW2 and can positively confirm that.

Comment: They are workout apps and use a `HKWorkoutSession` object to be able to run in the background. You can receive location updates during a workout session, but if your app isn't a real workout app it will likely get rejected from the AppStore for using `HKWorkoutSession` just to get location updates.

Comment: Except for native apps. Native apps have "special permissions" and they can stay in foreground even if they're not running a workout session or playing audio.

Comment: Yes, I meant system apps, and I pointed it out to make clear why some apps (e.g. timer) can run in the foreground indefinitely.

Comment: I know this is a subsequent question, but it’s still sort of on topic.
When my app is in the dock, (without implementing any background modes or HealthKit stuff) it continues to run until I scroll the app out of view. When I scroll the Dock view to display my app again, it resumes running. I determine this as my app displays the time.
So are there two states of an app in the Dock: 1) While displayed and 2) while not displayed ?

Comment: The fact that your app displays its view in the dock doesn't mean it's actually running in the background. `watchOS` calls some methods to let your app update its snapshot displayed in the Dock using a  [WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wksnapshotrefreshbackgroundtask).